# Using VBA in Excel, move rows of cells to Master

Tags: excel, vba

Using VBA, how can I have users automatically, before save, move (not copy) row(s) of data from their sheet to last row of master?

5 individual sheets/users inputting same type of data (tracking their programming data). When user saves, their rows of data on their sheet needs to be moved to master sheet for further analysis. These rows once moved should not exist in individual sheet.

Thank you, in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you able to intercept the SAVE / SAVE AS command?

Comment: Cut and Paste an option?

Comment: Thank you both for the responses.

Comment: FDavidov - I can intercept SAVE/SAVE AS. I just thought BeforeSave might lend to a more fluid interaction with the user.   What do you have in mind?

Comment: J Reid - I need more of an automated process.  Cut and Pastes could lead to Gone and Forgotten

Answer (score 1):

My comment may not have been clear, I meant Cut-Paste as part of your function like this ...

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim Master As Worksheet
Dim LastRow_Master As Integer
Dim LastRow_Current As Integer

Set Master = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   If Not ws Is Master Then
      LastRow_Master = Master.Cells(Master.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
      LastRow_Current = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

      If LastRow_Current > 1 Then
         ws.Rows("2:" & LastRow_Current).Cut Master.Rows(LastRow_Master)
      End If

   End If
Next

Application.CutCopyMode = 0

End Sub
```

*Note: I assume every worksheet has a header at Row 1. Including the Master.*

Comment: J Reid - Thank you!